# How do I get the state from useSelector after dispatch is done?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a FormCheck component that calls the handleChange function on the onChange event. Task: change the state of the checkbox, and send a request to the server with the new state. The problem is that the submission is done later, i.e. the getSelectedCategories function is executed before the submission.

```
const data = useSelector((state) => state.products);
const boxes = getBoxes(data);


const handleChange = (id) => {
    dispatch(setFilterCategory(id));
    const selectedCategories = getSelectedCategories(data);
    console.log(selectedCategories); // This is done before the dispatch while the state changes
    dispatch(fetchProducts(selectedCategories); 
};

return (
  {boxes.map(item => {
     return <FormCheck label={item.value} checked={item.isChecked} onChange={() => handleChange(item.id)}
  })}
);
```

Comment: can you show getSelectedCategories?

Comment: Could you provide a working example with Codesandbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By definition, callbacks defined in the body of a function component can only access state, props, and values that existed when the callback was created *at the time the component rendered*.

If you're dispatching an action, it's impossible for that code to access the *new* Redux state (or even React state) on the next line.

If you do need to access the new Redux state immediately, you can do that via a thunk, which has access to `getState`:

```js
const updateCategoryAndFetch = (category) => {
  return (dispatch, getState) => {
      dispatch(setFilterCategory(id));
      const selectedCategories = getSelectedCategories(getState());
    dispatch(fetchProducts(selectedCategories)
  }
}

// later, in the component:

const handleChange = (id) => {
  dispatch(updateCategoryAndFetch(id));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what `useEffect()` is made for:

```
const data = useSelector((state) => state.products);
const selectedCategories = getSelectedCategories(data);

const handleChange = (id) => {
    dispatch(setFilterCategory(id));
};

// is executed whenever selectedCategories changes
useEffect(() => {
  dispatch(fetchProducts(selectedCategories);
}, [selectedCategories])
```